# Wordpress Comment - Name after Comment

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm trying to modify the way the comments are shown in Wordpress.. I cannot find the way to output the name of the commenter AFTER the Comment Message. How can i create this? Maybe jquery? Maybe editing the comments php ? I Cant see the way to do it when I open my comments.php file

have a look:

```
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php

// Do not delete these lines   if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

  if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>      <div class="help">
        <p class="nocomments">This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>     </div>   <?php
    return;   } ?>

<!-- You can start editing here. -->

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>       <h5 id="comments" class="h5"><?php comments_number('<span>No</span> Responses', '<span>One</span> Response', '<span>%</span> Responses' );?> to &#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;</h5>

    <nav id="comment-nav">      <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><?php previous_comments_link() ?></li>
            <li><?php next_comments_link() ?></li>      </ul>   </nav>      <ol class="commentlist">        <?php wp_list_comments('callback=qs_comments'); ?>  </ol>       <nav id="comment-nav">      <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><?php previous_comments_link() ?></li>
            <li><?php next_comments_link() ?></li>      </ul>   </nav>
    <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

    <?php else : // comments are closed ?>  <!-- If comments are closed.
-->     <!--<p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>-->

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>

<?php comment_form(); ?>

<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

This is the way they show now: check the IMAGE below

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. I cannot seem to find the way to change this. Where can I find the "basic" comment structure ...I'm really lost. Should I edit directly the WP core files??? How can I do something more neat?

Comment: I have found the answer to the question. I cant post an answer because my reputation is to bad :O but dont desperate: here I share a link to the code I was looking for the last hour: http://jsfiddle.net/glowzar/ce7kR/

Comment: Dear Rhys, I have a problem now, the comments are showing in all the pages, even that I have deactivated them using a plugin for all the pages except one. Seems that my code lacks of something that works with the Disable Comments Master WP plugin. I cannot seem to find out which is the problem.